# How to cache invoices per user in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, caching

I have an app where a user can signup, create a customer, then create an invoice for that customer.  The invoice has lineitems and images attached.

Now I want to use action caching and fragment caching on the invoices.  How should I name the fragment caches so that they're only used for that specific user?  (Using devise).  I was thinking of putting the Invoice ID and User ID inside the cached fragment name, is that the "Rails" way of doing this?

Comment: I'm not sure that there is a Rails way to do this other than trying to keep things simple. If invoices are unique to a customer, do you really need the User ID? Would just the Invoice ID suffice?

Comment: @Beerlington No, because then someone can go to app.com/invoices/35 if that's not their invoice and see it.